# Cannot load the model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I've done training the NN, and I saved the model and loaded it again. I got this error.

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'projection_dim'
```

I cannot understand why and what is the problem.
This is my code that included the projection_dim

```
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, **kwargs):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.prj_dim = projection_dim
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )

    def call(self, patch):
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
        a = self.prj_dim
        return encoded

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'num_patches': self.num_patches,
            'projection': self.projection,
            'position_embedding': self.position_embedding,
            'prj_dim': self.prj_dim   
            })
        return config
```

This is the link to the google colab notebook for anyone who is interested.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LPi_xPe6kFV1eNTKWwHq1onJsDXep_Mj?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `prj_dim` to `projection_dim` in `get_config` method as it expects the positional argument `projection_dim`. This way -

```py
def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({
        'num_patches': self.num_patches,
        'projection': self.projection,
        'position_embedding': self.position_embedding,
        'projection_dim': self.prj_dim   
        })
    return config
```